# What are the requirements for Core Data to work with Canvas Previews - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, canvas, swiftui, preview, mobile-application

I have a small struct that returns a single row to a List from my 'Property' Core Data entity as a navigation link.

Here is the call to the struct inside my List:

```
List {
  ForEach(properties, id: \.address) {
    PropertyRow(property: $0)
  }
  .onDelete(perform: deleteProperty)
}
```

This is what my struct looks like:

```
import CoreData
import SwiftUI

struct PropertyRow: View {
    
    let property: Property
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink(destination: PropertyDetails(property: property)){
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text(property.address ?? "Unknown Address")
                    Spacer()
                    Text(property.city ?? "Unknown City")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My issue is that I can't figure out how to make the canvas show the preview even though there are no errors and the app runs in the simulator. Here is what I have written:

```
struct PropertyRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        
    static let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    
    static var previews: some View {
        
        let property = Property(context: moc)
        property.address = "123 Main St."
        property.city = "Columbia"
        property.state = "SC"
        property.zip = "29153"
        
        return NavigationView {
            PropertyRow(property: property)
        }
    }
```

What data is preview expecting that I am forgetting about?

Comment: But `Property(context: context)` creates empty object, so view has just nothing to show. Fill that object with some values. ... and `property.address.map(Text.init)` is weird for SwiftUI :), Try instead `Text(property.address ?? "")` - doesn't it look better?

Comment: Thanks for the help with the Text fields. I still am having trouble giving values to the object. I added 3 lines of code after creating the context. 1 - `let property = Property(context: context)` 2 - `property.address = "123 Main St."` 3 - `property.city = "Columbia"`. I then changed the final statement to read `return PropertyRow(property: property)` since the preview has to conform to the View protocol. I also tried adding a call to my save context method but that didn't seem to fix the issue either.

Comment: Update: I found a video by Paul Hudson on YouTube "Showing book details – Bookworm SwiftUI Tutorial 7/10" which seemed to address the problem, but I still don't have preview working. I am updating the question now to reflect a few key changes. 1 - I  added `import CoreData` at the top. 2 - I created a static variable for the Managed Object Context before the preview's View is created with `static let moc = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)`. 3 - I returned inside a Navigation View `return NavigationView {  PropertyRow(property: property)  }`